# Database search for product - advanced

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, search

I have a database filled with product names, eg: `HD 265;HD265;HD 265DT`. My problem is I need to return all 3 variants when I enter the search query `HD 265DT`. How does search engines solves this problem without defining all 3 variants in all rows for these products?

Comment: Did you really use `;` separated values?  I advice you to read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What you can do is make a loop in the application code where you split unique parts out off the search string  `HD 265DT`  meaning `HD`, `265` and `DT` as a part. And query more or less like `SELECT DISTINCT table.* FROM (SELECT 'HD' AS searchword UNION SELECT '256' AS searchword ....) AS search_filter INNER JOIN table ON table.column LIKE CONCAT('%', search_filter.searchword, '%')` ... Ofcource this approah can't make use of indexes.. The beter approach would be to create a search_part table based on the product names index that and query those records..

Comment: @RaymondNijland `;` I used only to visualize variations, of course these values stored in `product_name` column row. :) When I got to realize this is some advanced search I went almost the same route you suggested except I split search query at space than used this way `SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%HD%' AND name LIKE '%265%' AND name LIKE '%265DT%'` this approach doesn't use indexes either. Full text search is no option sadly.

Comment: Also I quote my colleague who work with my program "I do not know how or what to enter to find the product", like me neither, she fill the form/database with the data. I couldn't know either that after `265` the `DT` is optional.

Comment: if you don't know it how should the A.I know how to handle it..

Comment: I would want to go that way. I used a little trick earlier something like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE 'HD265DT' LIKE 'HD265DT'` the actual text after `WHERE` is the `name` column, where I replace white-space with empty string during query on both column and query value. Which worked until the optional `DT`.

Comment: "Full text search is no option sadly" The approach i tell you isn't Full text search.. FULL text search works with `MATCH()`  Besides [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qE8Vk59fMAZdHEbmS2ZGMy/0

Comment: @RaymondNijland yes I am aware what you suggested is not showing how to search the database table using full text search, or adding, combining full text indexes together.

Comment: If fulltext search is not an option, then how come this question is tagged with elasticsearch? One of the key features of elasticsearch is fulltext search.

Comment: The only way i can think off after seeing the data is splitting the product_data into digits and query it.. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qE8Vk59fMAZdHEbmS2ZGMy/3 the only problem is you need to generate the search table and update it when inserting, updating and deleting meaning you have to need triggers.. Besides you store the data duplicated sure mine approach could have been more optimizated it's just a example.. Besides it needs to have a update https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qE8Vk59fMAZdHEbmS2ZGMy/4 that is really uses the position..

Comment: It is a really interesting approach also I think I can re-use your solution to everywhere else and make the search even faster, easier. I'm thinking to replace `source_id` with product EAN this way I could reduce the amount of data stored in lookup table. Thank you @RaymondNijland!

Comment: @RaymondNijland I was working with the examples you shared with me. Almost perfect just one thing, using `IN()` finds everything and `FIND_IN_SET()` find nothing aka it works like `LIKE` search. Could you tell me more about this approach, how it is called so I could read more about this.